# Apatar for feeding data into Solr

Tags: solr, etl, data-migration

I need to fetch data from normalized MSSQL db and feed them in Solr index.

I was just wondering whether Apatar can be used to perform the job. I've gone through its documents, but doesn't get the information I'm looking for. It states, it can fetch data from SQL server, and post it over HTTP, but still not sure, whether it can post fetched data in XML over http or not?

Any advise will be highly valuable. thank you

Comment: [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) is not sufficient for some reason?

Comment: I'm just evaluating options, so decide on suitable implementation plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Apatar, but seeing as it is a Java application, it may be a bit challenging to implement it in a windows environment. However, for various scenarios where I need to fetch data from a MSSQL Database and feed it to Solr, I have written custom C# code leveraging the SolrNet client. This tends to be pretty straight forward and simple code and in the cases where we need to load data at specified intervals we are using scheduled tasks calling a console application. I would recommend checking out the [Create/Update](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/CRUD) section of the SolrNet site for some examples of loading/updating data with the .Net client.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to do this... also trying with DIH as well... thank you.